# Image load time takes longer in html and php pages?

Tags: php, html, performance, web-services, time

It been like 1 week already i am trying to solve this without success , The images inside my server loads fast when i open them directly ex: [direct URL](http://walldice.com/images/sea.png) it takes around **130ms** while showing the same image in html or php ex: [inside page](http://walldice.com/wall-asd%20%20%20cat%20%20black%20%20animals-14102.htm) pages takes around 20X longer load time **2.52s**.

I have noticed that this problem happens in inner pages only while index.php works fine.

I though at first its a codding error or something but then i have made a test page that only have this code on it `<img class="logo-btn" src="images/logo.png" />`
 [Test Page](http://walldice.com/speedtest1.html) and the load time for the same image is **2.5s** , while it takes only **130ms** in the [direct URL](http://walldice.com/images/sea.png) as i said.

Comment: This is either a server side issue, or a script on your page that is causing things to load more slowly. You need to go through and check which scripts you are loading (Javascript), don't link to external scripts, download them if you can and add them to your website files. The server side issue would be low bandwidth, low specs and things like that which make it load slow.

Comment: i have made a new page that only have image tag on it no scripts no php nothing just 1 html img tag with the same logo image and it take 2.5 sec to load !, and about the server side issue that might be but its not bandwith or low specs , i am confused whats causing this ! in the home page it works fine !